# How can i cover the stochastic integral on the negative side

Tags: manipulate

```
z = 1; (*z is constant set to 1*)
f[j_] := j/(z^2 + j^2)^(3/2);
Integrate[f[j], j]
xlast = 5.0; xinit = -2.5;
pltf = Plot[f[j], {j, xinit, xlast}, Filling -> Axis];
Print[pltf]
nintegratef = NIntegrate[f[j], {j, xinit, xlast}];
Print[nintegratef]
```

[image]

```
findmax = FindMaximum[f[j], {j, xlast}]
fmax = findmax[[1]];
L = xlast - xinit;
A = fmax*L; (* build the rectangular box with dimension fmax x L *)

totalcountmax = 10000;
For[i = 1, i <= totalcountmax, i++,
  inbox[i] = {0, 0};
  missed[i] = {0, 0};
  ];

inboxcount = 0; countmissed = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= totalcountmax, i++,
 xrand = RandomReal[{xinit, xlast}];
 yrand = RandomReal[{0, fmax}];
 If[0 <= yrand <= f[xrand],
  inbox[i] = {xrand, yrand};
  inboxcount = inboxcount + 1;
  ,(*else, record the missed points*)
  missed[i] = {xrand, yrand};
  countmissed = countmissed + 1;
  ];(*end if*)
 Countinbox[i] = inboxcount;
 Countmissed[i] = countmissed;
 ];(*end for i*)


tinbox[q_] := Table[inbox[i], {i, 1, q}];
tmissed[q_] := Table[missed[i], {i, 1, q}];
gp[q_] := Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.01], Point[tinbox[q]]}];
gpm[q_] := Graphics[{Yellow, PointSize[0.01], Point[tmissed[q]]}
   ];
pltfj[q_] := 
  Plot[f[j], {j, xinit, xlast}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> {q, Style[Countmissed[q], Yellow],
     Style[Countinbox[q], Green]
     }];

Manipulate[Show[pltfj[q], gpm[q], gp[q]], {q, 1, totalcountmax, 1}]
integratestochastic = A*inboxcount/totalcountmax;
Print["{nintegratef,integratestochastic,A,totalcountmax,inboxcount}", \
{nintegratef, integratestochastic, A, totalcountmax, inboxcount}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your `For` loop to account for positive and negative regions, and make the box twice as big.  First change the definition of `A`,

```
A = 2 fmax*L;
```

Then modify your `For` loop to be

```
posinboxcount = 0;
neginboxcount = 0;
countmissed = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= totalcountmax, i++,
  xrand = RandomReal[{xinit, xlast}];
  yrand = RandomReal[{-fmax, fmax}];
  If[0 <= Sign[f[xrand]] yrand <= Sign[f[xrand]] f[xrand],
    inbox[i] = {xrand, yrand};
  If[Sign[yrand] == 1,
   posinboxcount = posinboxcount + 1;,
   neginboxcount = neginboxcount + 1;]
    ,(*else, record the missed points*)
    missed[i] = {xrand, yrand};
    countmissed = countmissed + 1;
    ];(*end if*)
  Countinbox[i] = posinboxcount + neginboxcount;
  Countmissed[i] = countmissed;
  ];(*end for i*)
```

and finally your definition for the integral,

```
integratestochastic = A*(posinboxcount - neginboxcount)/totalcountmax;
```

Now you will get

[image]

If you want to write this more compactly, taking advantage of the built-in functions in *Mathematica*, then you could calculate the area like

```
region = Rectangle[{xinit, -fmax}, {xlast, fmax}];
sample = RandomPoint[region, 100000];
poscounts = Select[sample, 0 < #[[2]] < f[#[[1]]] &];
negcounts = Select[sample, 0 > #[[2]] > f[#[[1]]] &];
Area[region] (Length@poscounts - Length@negcounts)/Length[sample]

(* 0.173436 *)
```

And you can make a graphics like

```
xlast = 5.0;
xinit = -2.5;
z = 1;
f[j_] := j/(z^2 + j^2)^(3/2);
nintegratef = NIntegrate[f[j], {j, xinit, xlast}];
findmax = FindMaximum[f[j], {j, xlast}]
fmax = findmax[[1]];
region = Rectangle[{xinit, -fmax}, {xlast, fmax}];
sample = RandomPoint[region, 10000];
Manipulate[
 Module[{poscounts, negcounts, missed},
  poscounts = Select[sample[[;; q]], 0 < #[[2]] < f[#[[1]]] &];
  negcounts = Select[sample[[;; q]], 0 > #[[2]] > f[#[[1]]] &];
  missed = Complement[sample[[;; q]], poscounts, negcounts];
  Column[{
    Show[
     Plot[f[j], {j, xinit, xlast}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400],
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point@negcounts,
       Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point@poscounts,
       Yellow, PointSize[0.01], Point@missed}]],
    Grid[{{"Npoints = ", q},
      {"Positive counts = ", Length[poscounts]},
      {"Negative counts = ", Length[negcounts]},
      {"Calculated area = ", 
       Area[region] (Length@poscounts - Length@negcounts)/q},
      {"Actual area = ", nintegratef}}]
    }]
  ]
 , {{q, Length@sample}, 1, Length@sample, 1}]
```

[image]